# SQL Query: Need to change multiple field values to NULL

Tags: sql

SQL Query amateur here.....I have a database with multiple tables each containing multiple fields.  The data in some of the fields in sensitive and needs to be changed to NULL.  How can I create a single query that will define the fields in a table i need to change and have the content of the fields, irregardless of what it is, changed to NULL.

For example, I need to change all Social Security Number, Birthdate, and HomePhone fields in all records to a NULL Value.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: do you want to just delete those columns instead?

Comment: it is for a study so i need to keep the fields just trash the data

Answer (score 6):

```
update YourTable 
set
SS = null,
Birthdate = null,
HomePhone = null
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an UPDATE query for each table.
You can do something like:

UPDATE TABLE1 SET SecurityNumber=NULL, Birthdate=NULL

UPDATE TABLE2 SET HomePhone=NULL

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you could do this with a simple procedure.  Here is the idea in pl/sql.. you can adjust the conditionals to whatever you need

```
for i in(SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length FROM 
USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'YOURTABLE')
  Loop
  colname := i.column_name;
  IF i.data_type = 'VARCHAR2' THEN
  execute immediate 'update YOURTABLE set '|| colname || ' = null where ' || 
colname || ' = ''NA''';
  ELSIF i.data_type = 'DATE' THEN
  execute immediate 'update YOURTABLE  set '|| colname || ' = null where ' || 
colname || ' < ''01-JAN-2010''';
  End If;
  End Loop;
COMMIT;
```